# Difficulty understanding Chi-Squared p-values in this case

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Forgive me, but I'm new to this. I have two columns of categorical data. The data represents access to a particular resource, where a 1 indicates that the individual accessed the resource and a 0 indicates they did not. Each column represents a different sample of the population. I am using a chi-squared test on the contingency table. I am hoping to investigate whether the two samples do in fact come from the same population. I find that my P value is large (like p = 0.65). Do I have evidence to suggest that the two samples come from the same population, or at least, do I have evidence to suggest that they do not come from different populations? I'm struggling to wrap my head around the interpretation of the various hypotheses.

Comment: Chi-square is a test of association. That's not exactly the same as whether they come from the same population. But your notion is one of "accepting the null" which is against the rules. You can only "fail to reject" the null.   So, you do not have evidence that sample is related to access.

Comment: I see, but I think I'm still not quite clear - I do not have evidence that sample is related to access - this would mean that I do not have evidence to say that because someone is from sample A, therefore their access is likely to be X? Or, more importantly, I do not have evidence to state that which sample you come from affects how you accessed?

Comment: Both of those. In fact, with only two samples, those two statements are equivalent.

Comment: @peterfloam thank you. If you post that as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chi-square is a test of association. That's not exactly the same as whether they come from the same population. But your notion is one of "accepting the null" which is against the rules. You can only "fail to reject" the null. So, you do not have enough evidence that sample is related to access to be able to reject the null.

Comment: "Don't have evidence" isn't correct, either.  What if the underlying counts run into the billions (to take one extreme)?  Few people would seriously claim a large p-value is a lack of evidence!  More accurately, this result merely shows there isn't sufficient evidence to reject the null.

Comment: That's true. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks both. FWIW, I have only a few dozen data points, so not really a concern about billions, but I see your point :)

Answer (score 9):

While you're doing a test of association, that's the same thing as a test of homogeneity of proportions (in spite of many people suggesting there's a distinction; there isn't -- assuming none of the population proportions are exactly $0$, the hypotheses of independence and homogeneity of proportions are different ways to say the same thing about the population - each implies the other, it follows from the definition of independence in probability).

However, even if you could establish that two sets of proportions are homogeneous, that doesn't of itself seem to establish that the samples *came from the same population*, only that the population proportions happened to be the same. The distributions are the same, the populations they were drawn from may be distinct collections; they might be clearly separated - e.g. in time and space - and may have always been so. The two statements are not always logically equivalent so a little care may be required in how we express it.

> I find that my P value is large (like p = 0.65). Do I have evidence to suggest that the two samples come from the same population, or at least, do I have evidence to suggest that they do not come from different populations?

Neither of those! You lack evidence against $H_0$. While the data are consistent (in a particular sense) with homogeneous proportions, the data are also consistent with a range of proportions that are not homogeneous (there are hypotheses distinct from that $H_0$ that would also not be rejected in a test on the data you have; if your samples are small there may be a very wide range of such potential hypotheses). Clearly if there are mutually-exclusive possible nulls that would not be rejected you can't reasonably claim that non-rejection of a particular one of them is the case.

> I am hoping to investigate whether the two samples do in fact come from the same population.

Generally speaking, you can't establish that the population parameters (population proportions) are identical from a non-exhaustive sample.